# How can I navigate from an html file to another with a spotify uri?

Tags: hyperlink, navigation, spotify

I don't understand how to navigate through an app with multiple .html files. All the examples that I've found have only one html file.

I have two files in my app :

- index.html
- artist.html

In my `index.html`, I use a `<a href="artist.html">Text</a>`, which works but does not add a state in the history.

From what I have read in the documentation, I should use a link like `spotify:app:$APPNAME:arg`. But I can't manage to make a link like this works to navigate from an html file to another. And because I can only find apps with one html, I'm wondering if all the existing apps only show and hide parts of an html file to simulate the navigation.

Answer (score 1):

You can link internal with:

```
sp://appname/filename.ext
```

Comment: But it doesn't push the page in the history. I want to use a link AND push the state in the history (like if I'm using a spotify:app:X-like uri).

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes it a bit harder. The only description I can find about internal linking in the guidelines from Spotify is that you should link with sp://

Comment: Link to guidelines: http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/01_integration-guidelines.html#architecture

Answer (score 0):

link to `spotify:app:appname:test`.

At this point in index.html you can redirect to the page you want (I.e. test.html) using:

`location.href=sp.core.getArguments() + '.html'`

The initial call to `spotify:app:appname:test` will be in the history.